# Finding Inverse Cosine in Radians

Tags: java

This gives me the answer in degrees but I want the answer in Radians for Inverse Cosine. 
For example if I pick 0.5 for invCosineVal it will return 60 deg but not sure how I can find the answer in Radians which should be 1.047.

```
ans = Math.acos(invCosineVal) * (180/Math.PI);
```

Comment: You really need to refresh your basic trigonometry... **and read the Javadoc of `Math.acos`**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ans = Math.acos(invCosineVal)
```

There you go, 180/Math.PI converts it to degrees